# Base64 encoded JWT token validation using KONG

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I have a java code which generates a JWT token using Jwts.builder().
However, the generated token is then again encoded using a Base64 encoder, e.g.

Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(token.getBytes())

I have been able to setup kong to validate the generated JWT token but I can not find a way to validate the Base64 encoded version of the token.

Can you please suggest if there is a way to handle such a scenario.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a ready-to-use solution, however you can:

- either clone the original [jwt plugin](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/kong/plugins/jwt/jwt_parser.lua) and adapt the code so you can handle the base64 encoded string
- or write your own plugin `base64 decoder` to decode it properly and then use the original jwt-plugin. You can control the [order of execution](https://docs.konghq.com/2.0.x/plugin-development/custom-logic/) so your custom plugin runs before the jwt plugin and replaces the original double-encoded token with the single-coded (normal) jwt token

To stay close to the original plugin and avoid code duplication, I would recommend the second way.